# How would I calculate the Present value of a perpetuity growing at a fixed dollar amount - not a fixed rate?

Tags: finance

Calculating the present value of a growing perpetuity is relatively straight forward. However how would i go about calculating the present value of a perpetuity growing at a fixed dollar amount.  That is, the perpetuity pays 1 at the end of the first year, 2 at the end of the second year, 3 at the end of the third year... $n at the end of the nth year,

I know that the stream can be thought as 1, 1 + 1, 1 + 2, 1 +3, 1 +1(n-1), factoring out the 1, just shifts the problem out by 1 year and this is where i am stumped as to what to do next.

Thanks in advance for your help or any hints as to where to go next

Comment: Better to add what you have tried to your answer.

Comment: The present value is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nv^n$  Do you know how to compute that?

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer?

Comment: I understand that it is Gabriels ladder - never took calculus - so some direction would be appreciated.  TIA